# Kohana i18n using database

Tags: php, database, orm, translation, kohana

I'm new to kohana and trying to modify i18n from file based to database based. Based on [this tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/files/i18n) I did following: Created new class `i18n` in `application/classes` directory to override default `__()` function.

```
<?php

class I18n extends Kohana_I18n
{


    function __($token, $lang = 'en')
    {
        $query = ORM::factory('Dictionary')->where('token', '=', $token)->find();
        return $query->{"txt_" . $lang};
    } 
}
```

I have dictionary model which looks like that

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Dictionary extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'Dictionary';

}
```

Got error message:

http://screencast.com/t/r84oL1A1

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion? Maybe class doesn't autoload?

Comment: "[...] based to databased based. Based [...]" What? huehue

Answer (score 0):

In this realisation you need to use in your View:

```
I18n::__($message_to_translate);
```

not

```
__($message_to_translate);
```

And you must declare `__()` function as **static**:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class I18n extends Kohana_I18n
{

    public static function __($token, $lang = 'en')
    {
        $query = ORM::factory('Dictionary')->where('token', '=', $token)->find();
        return $query->{"txt_" . $lang};
    } 
}
```